# How $\frac{1}{2}\Delta(\epsilon \vec E^2)=\epsilon (\Delta \vec E) \cdot \vec E$

Tags: derivatives, infinitesimals

> How $\frac{1}{2}\Delta(\epsilon \vec E^2)=\epsilon (\Delta \vec E) \cdot \vec E$

When I saw the expression, I thought they were differentiating (taking small changes in electric field)

$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta(\epsilon \vec E^2)=\frac{2}{2}\epsilon \vec E \Delta E$$ But I wonder where the dot product came from which confuses me about the expression.

Comment: What is $\vec{E}^2$ and $\Delta$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh $\vec E$ is electric field and $\Delta$ is infinitesimal increments.

Comment: well there is your answer - the quantity on the left is clearly a scalar so the quantity on left must be too hence the dot product

Comment: @NinadMunshi So my derivation $\frac{2}{2}\epsilon\vec E\Delta \vec E$ is correct(?) We just put dot product for make it scalar. And since cos theta will be 1 hence $\Delta \vec E \cdot \vec E =(\Delta  \vec E) \vec E$

Comment: Calling it is a derivation that you've done on your own is a stretch because you've provided 0 context for what this is about. I was working under the assumption that I was helping you follow the steps of a larger derivation done by someone who knew what they were doing, such as an instructor since sometimes they will use pedagogical tools that aren't perfectly rigorous to convey an idea.